# How to make pickle step for hash type field for mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pickle, mongoid

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :address, :type => Hash

end

Given a person exist with address: {:city => "city", :street => "street"}
```

Shows  undefined step as:

```
Given /^a person exists with address: \{:city => "([^"]*)", :street => "([^"]*)"\}$/ do |arg1, arg2|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

How can I  make it standard pickle step?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create the person and the address all in one step without creating your own step definition (which is pretty easy). You can split your feature into 2 lines like this:

```
Given an address exists with city: "Townsville" and street: "123 Main St."
And a person exists with address: the address
```

Comment: It seems that I couldn't explain clearly. Actually I need is like, if the attribute is of type Hash then how could it will be possible to add Hash type value to the attribute using pickle? I could add string/integer type value using general pickle steps as you explained above.

Comment: The whole point is how could we add value to attribute if the attribute is type hash, when we are testing using pickle?

Comment: Oh I see now. You'll need your own step definition then. Pickle doesn't let you pass arrays or hashes for attribute values (yet).